# Question about "in the game" used in this sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does 'in the game' mean in context?

"The forest was overflowing with life. It was abundant **in the game** sought by hunters, timber for the fire, and valuable herbs to process into medicine."

Comment: Alternatively, *The forest [**was abundant with life**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was+abundant+with+life%22). It was **overflowing in / with** the [type of] game [animals, which are] sought by hunters,...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LDOCE](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/game) has this definition of *game*, an uncountable noun:

> wild animals, birds, and fish that are hunted for food, especially as a sport

This kind of game is likely to be sought by hunters.